# NextAuth and Auth0 provider. Redirect to specific page after signup

Tags: auth0, next-auth

Im looking to redirect the user to a specific page after theyve signed up with Auth0.

After they sign up, i want them to set their username, profile pic, and some other info.

Ive got a button on the landing page that calls this function..

```
const login = async () => {
    await signIn("auth0", { // importing signIn from next-auth/react
        callbackUrl: "/dashboard",
    });
};
```

**[...nextauth].js**

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Auth0Provider from "next-auth/providers/auth0";

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        Auth0Provider({
            clientId: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
            issuer: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER,
            authorization: {
                params: {
                    prompt: "login",
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
        maxAge: 3000,
    },
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, account, user }) {
            if (account) {
                token.accessToken = account.access_token;
                token.id = user.id;
            }
            return token;
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
            session.user.id = token.id;

            return session;
        },
    },
});
```

**middleware.js**

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";

export const config = {
    matcher: [
        "/dashboard/:path*",
        "/devices/:path*",
        "/studios/:path*",
        "/account/:path*",
        "/settings/:path*",
    ],
};
```

When the user clicks the login button, the Auth0 login modal appears...

[image]

If the user signs in, they are redirected to the dashboard page, as specified in the signin function. But if they sign up instead of logging in, i want them to be redirected to the a different page.

I cant see how to detect if the user had signed up instead of signing in.